# Merge different "type" lists

Tags: f#, merge

I am relatively new to F#, but am really impressed with it so far, and despite having spent a lot of time searching and looking at the books I own I can not yet find an example of the following:
I have 3 (or more in reality) lists that are created from different input sources: database, CSV files, etc.  Assume the following structure for those lists:

```
type L1 = {
    Id : int32   // Common id
    StringFieldA : string
    StringFieldB : string
}

type L2 = {
    Id : int32   // Common id
    Ratio: decimal
    StringFieldC : string
}

type L3 = {
    Id : int32    // Common id
    Mean: decimal
    StringFieldD : string
}
```

I have methods that return F# lists of each of the above.  I now wish to merge the 3 lists, of different "types" into one - based on the common id - to a list as follows:

```
type Merged = {
    Id : int32
    StringFieldA : string
    StringFieldB : string
    StringFieldC : string
    StringFieldD : string
    Mean: decimal
    Ratio: decimal
}
```

How can I accomplish this in F#?  Sorry if I missed a sample else where.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming they're sorted and of equal length (if that's not the case I'm not sure what the merged result *should* be):

```
List.zip3 l1 l2 l3 |> List.map (fun (l1, l2, l3) ->
  { Id = l1.Id
    StringFieldA = l1.StringFieldA
    StringFieldB = l1.StringFieldB
    StringFieldC = l2.StringFieldC
    StringFieldD = l3.StringFieldD
    Mean = l3.Mean
    Ratio = l2.Ratio })
```

Comment: Yes - they are all sorted and of the exact same length - data about the same organizations, just received via different inputs (not my design...)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want - a discriminated union

```
type Data = 
    |First of L1
    |Second of L2
    |Third of L3
```

you could then add a Id member like

```
with member x.Id = 
    match x with
    |First(a) -> a.Id
    |Second(a) -> a.Id
    |Third(a) -> a.Id
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can sort each of the list by ID and zip them together, if all the list has the same ID set.

Comment: I don't think this will work for what he wants - you will end up with a `(L1 * L2 * L3) list`.  It also reqyures the three inputs to all have the same length

Comment: Zip is not the last operation, you need also to map the tuple into the final data you want.